# Autocomplete undefined id of selected item

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-ui

Im trying to print id of selected element in console but I got an undefined variable. In my Controller im returning a json with result from eloquent. Does anyone know what I did wrong? Controller looks like:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('term');

        $result = Recipe::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search. '%')->get();

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

My script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({

                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('autocomplete') }}",
                        data: {
                            term : request.term,
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                                return obj.name;
                            });

                            response(resp);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log(ui.item.id)
                },

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Data returned by function:

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "name":"Sa\u0142atka z makaronem i broku\u0142ami",
      "description":"Similique libero quas at qui architecto illum aliquam. Illo repellendus aperiam eos est. Ut ab rerum aliquid itaque qui. Aut officia rerum dolor illum est quod voluptatem.",
      "required_time":19,
      "level":5,
      "calories":613,
      "proteins":17,
      "fats":38,
      "carbs":25,
      "roughage":33,
      "created_at":"2019-12-09 00:04:55",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-09 00:04:55"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "name":"B\u0142yskawiczna sa\u0142atka jarzynowa",
      "description":"Ut commodi rem ut non beatae. Nam dolores inventore voluptates rerum perferendis. Quod asperiores aut saepe nam.",
      "required_time":81,
      "level":4,
      "calories":789,
      "proteins":46,
      "fats":10,
      "carbs":85,
      "roughage":65,
      "created_at":"2019-12-09 00:04:55",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-09 00:04:55"
   }, etc
```

Obj returned, as you can see obj have key id and values but when I try to use them when option is selected that returns me undefined.

```
{id: 1, name: "Lorem ipsum", description: "Similique libero quas at qui architecto illum aliq…ut officia rerum dolor illum est quod voluptatem.", required_time: 19, level: 5, …}
```

Comment: so console.log(data) returns undefined?

Comment: No, when I try to print console.log(ui.item.id) of selected element I got undefined

Comment: @JaroslawNowak Please provide an exmaple of your `obj` data. It looks like you're only sending an array of names back, so there would be no `id`.

Comment: @Twisty Updated my post and added returned obj and data of example elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the collection `toJson` method:

```
return response()->json($result->toJson());
```

Also if you need only the name just get back only those from the database, it will increase the time that your script takes to prefill the fields

Comment: When Im using toJson there is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'" error :/

Comment: Json.parse(data) inside the map should resolve this problem

Comment: Error resolved, but I still got undefined when Im trying to print id :(